Stealth Mosquitoes?
Have mosquitoes become silent and invisible, or am I losing my senses of hearing and sight?
This summer I have seen no mosquitoes and have only heard two of them, very quiet, as I sat on my sofa late at night and as they buzzed around my ears. And yet I am consistently bitten, often on the back of my hands and on the front of my forearms (where I should be able to see them feeding) whenever I go out. I don't see them, ever.
Previously I have caught mosquitoes as they fed on me, but this year not.
I live in Allentown PA. Is there a new breed of smaller, quieter stealthy mosquitoes, or what?
EDIT with new image
Following @anongoodnurse advice I have seen a killed four of these in my kitchen. Formerly I had disregarded them as harmless little bugs, because they were silent. I saw that they were definitely mosquitoes, but very small and very black. Two of them became black splots on the wall, the fourth looks like this:

It definitely has white stripes. This one is about 4mm long. They fly very slowly, and are completely silent. I swatted this one on my hand.

I'm up north of you in NY.  It has been a quiet mosquito season until the past few weeks.

@rtaft Noticed the same here. Don't know if mosquito activity was reduced during the hot weather, most likely it was because I didn't go out.

Definitely genus Aedes, maybe A. japonicus (less white than the Asian Tiger, A. albopictus)? Nice update!

Your sight and hearing are probably fine. You might be experiencing the relatively recent population growth of Asian Tiger Mosquitoes, a tiny, quiet mosquito that first appeared in Houston, Texas in 1985.
From the PennState Extension:

Over 60 species of mosquitoes can be found in Pennsylvania... Two invasive mosquito species, the yellow fever mosquito (Aedes aegypti) and the Asian tiger mosquito (Aedes albopictus) have been found in southern Pennsylvania; however, their range may change and move further north.

From the French Agency for Food, Environmental and Occupational Health & Safety, it is:

Noiseless and diurnal: in contrast with the common mosquito (Culex) which tends to bite at night and which makes noise when flying, the tiger mosquito is diurnal, in other words it bites during the day (mainly in the morning and the evening), and it makes no noise.

Small: This species of mosquito is actually quite small, less than 5 mm in length.

Black and white stripes: ...the tiger mosquito is not yellow and black but white and black.  It is also characterized by the presence of a white dorsal line along its thorax. Its legs also have stripes.


In Southcentral PA, I am only two counties west of you, so not far. Mosquitoes don't seem to be particularly attracted to me, and the few times I've been bitten this summer (on my forearms), it was a complete surprise, and by the time I realized it the mosquito was becoming engorged. More frustrating is that each time it was during afternoon daylight, a time which used to be mosquitoless. They were Asian Tiger Mosquitoes.


I'll keep an extra close eye open for them.

More of a joke than a comment but ability to hear high frequencies decreases significantly with years aged even in young, "healthy" individuals (i.e. Wang et al, 2021) so it might very well both be new kind of mosquitos and a (slight? subclinical except for those damn mosquitos?) decrease in hearing compared to the year before :)

@Narusan Could be. They are much smaller than "regular" mosquitoes and their rapid wing beats might put the sound frequency up near ultrasound range. As I mentioned I have heard mosquitoes in the quiet of the evening, in my living room.

I've lived in Texas most of my life, and to me these are regular mosquitos! I guess that explains why I never really heard the stereotypical "mosquito noise" much

@RadvylfPrograms Oh my word! I've only ever heard the high, annoying whine of mosquitos until a short few years ago. At least it was a warning to beware. These little creatures take me totally by surprise!

Finally tracked the little blighters to their lair. They have been using the water in our lucky bamboo to hatch their nefarious plots.

Translation of mosquito whine:  This won’t hurt a bit. There may be a little discomfort later: swelling and itching. Just remain calm while I take a small blood sample.  (In a small percentage of operations there may be serious side effects: West Nile fever, dengue fever . . . . .)

@anongoodnurse Sincere thanks to you. Previously I had seen these small flying bugs which I considered slightly annoying but innocuous and had just waved them away. Since receiving your answer I have assiduously hunted down and swatted eight of these in my home. As a result, rather than being bitten two or three times every day I have only been bitten once in the last two days, the perpetrator of which is in the photo in my question.

@Rich - My pleasure! I learn things, too, when I answer, like how very little water these things need to reproduce. I was surprised and chagrined; I found that they were breeding in a tiny pool of water that collected in a broken piece of pottery in my garden (which I had been watering due to the heat). I've been supplying the neighbors with mosquitoes without realizing it. So we both got more than just "reputation" points! :)
