Is it possible that mosquitoes have been laying eggs and reproducing inside my house?
I am in Southern India. It is the rainy season now, so plenty of mosquitoes everywhere. I like to think my house is pretty well sealed off with mosquito nets in all openings, though.
Once in a while, a few get through when opening the door, etc.
However, I recently got these indoor pots with "self watering" pots. That just means there is a little compartment underneath the pot where you pour water in, which is connected to the soil, enabling the plant to absorb water from it.
Now, I have noticed way more mosquitoes lately inside my house. Sometimes, one of them manages to get a good, full size bite in. Sometimes I swat one and it is full of blood, so it already bit me.
It suddenly occured to me, could these guys (or gals, I should say) have been laying eggs inside the water resevoirs of my pots? The opening is plenty big for a mosquito.
This would explain the large number of mosquitoes in my house lately.
The other option is that it just the rainy season and they are somehow making it through some opening in a mesh or something, or through the door when I go in and out.

You have your answer. See also https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/115255/5198; user had the same problem.

Take a look in the water reservoirs. If they're reproducing in there, you'll probably be able to see the larvae. Little black wriggly fellas.

But the larvae do need something to eat. This could be plant litter, e.g., if any has fallen into the reservoir, or algae, if the reservoir gets enough light for algae to grow. Otherwise, I'd be pretty surprised if they were successfully reproducing in there.

@Eonema they need a very little amount to eat, a combination of drinking water and house dust in a lot of cases is pretty much enough. And I live in southern Europe and not India...

worth noting it can't be perfectly sealed, you get in, that tends ot be when the bugs come in, riding or hovinring around people.

Some species of mosquito can reproduce in very small amounts of water, as small as about a bottle-cap in volume. This is a known feature of Aedes albopictus, the so-called Tiger mosquito. The closely related Aedes aegypti can also do the same.
So long as there is room for the adult female to get in and lay her eggs, then there is potential for those pots to be a breeding site for mosquitoes. The bad news is that for some species of mosquito, the eggs can withstand drying for up to 8 months, so even drying the pots out might not work. You would need to empty the pot and then scrub them out to ensure that you have gotten rid of any eggs. Apparently bleach (sodium hypochlorite) is also effective at some concentrations starting around 1% (standard household bleach is anywhere between about 2.5 and 5%), but you would need to submerge the containers in the bleach for at least 24 hours.
A simple solution might be to seal the containers with a piece of netting to contain any mosquitoes that might be in there and prevent any new ones from getting in.

Thanks! I closed the opening of the resevoirs
